# Is there a way to get subdataframes with purrr in magrittr pipes workflow without using data.frame name?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, purrr

That is, I was interested in doing the same as in the example, but with `purrr` functions.

```r
tibble(a, b = a * 2, c = 1) %>% 
    {lapply(X = names(.), FUN = function(.x) select(., 1:.x))}
[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 1
      a
  <int>
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5

[[2]]
# A tibble: 5 x 2
      a     b
  <int> <dbl>
1     1     2
2     2     4
3     3     6
4     4     8
5     5    10

[[3]]
# A tibble: 5 x 3
      a     b     c
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     1
2     2     4     1
3     3     6     1
4     4     8     1
5     5    10     1
```

I only could do it if I named `foo <- tibble(a, b = a * 2, c = 1)` and inside `map` I did `select(foo, ...)`, but I wanted to avoid that, since I wanted to mutate the named dataframe in pipe workflow.

Thank you!

Comment: What is wrong in replacing `lapply` with `map` ? `tibble(a = 1:5, b = a * 2, c = 1) %>% 
  {map(names(.), function(.x) select(., 1:.x))}`

Comment: I had tried very similar codes to yours getting always errors. In fact, I had tried the same but with `{map(names(.), ~select(., 1:.x))}` instead of `function(.x)`, which does not work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` in the following way :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

tibble(a = 1:5, b = a * 2, c = 1) %>%    
  {map(names(.), function(.x) select(., 1:.x))}
```

Based on your actual use case you can also use `imap` which will pass column value (`.x`) along with it's name (`.y`).

```
tibble(a = 1:5, b = a * 2, c = 1) %>%    
  imap(function(.x, .y) select(., 1:.y))

#$a
# A tibble: 5 x 1
#      a
#  <int>
#1     1
#2     2
#3     3
#4     4
#5     5

#$b
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#      a     b
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     1     2
#2     2     4
#3     3     6
#4     4     8
#5     5    10

#$c
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#      a     b     c
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     1
#2     2     4     1
#3     3     6     1
#4     4     8     1
#5     5    10     1
```